# jal mips not doing anything

Tags: mips

my goal is to swap the values in the swap: function

however it's not doing anything.

i set the values of a0 and a1 to whatever and it doesn't overwrite their values.
i am not allowed to use t0, I have to use the stack.

still, why isn't it doing anything to a0 and a1, do I have to return something in v0?

```
    .text
main:
    la  $a0,n1
    la  $a1,n2
    jal     swap
    li  $v0,1   # print n1 and n2; should be 27 and 14
    lw  $a0,n1
    syscall
    li  $v0,11
    li  $a0,' '
    syscall
    li  $v0,1
    lw  $a0,n2
    syscall
    li  $v0,11
    li  $a0,'\n'
    syscall
    li  $v0,10  # exit
    syscall

swap:


    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $a0, 0($sp)
    addi $a0, $a1, 0
    lw $a1, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4        
    jr $ra


L1: 

    .data
n1: .word   14
n2: .word   27
```

Answer (score 1):

You're swapping *pointers*, not the values they point *to*. And when you print the values you read them directly from `n1` and `n2` instead of through the pointers you swapped.

To fix this you could:

- Load the values of `n1` and `n2` (rather than their addresses) before calling `swap`. Then print `$a0` and `$a1` afterwards, instead of re-loading the values from `n1` and `n2`.
- Dereference the pointers inside swap in order to actually swap the values.
- Dereference the pointers before doing the `print_int` syscall, instead of reading the values to print directly from `n1` and `n2`.

The first solution would be the easiest.